# Vuetify: changing min-height of v-application--wrap

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a vuetify component as a widget on a page along with another content after the widget. However, I have too much free space between the widget and the rest of the page. The vuetify app  takes too much height and I can't figure out how to remove it.

Here's how it look in the browser.

I have tried to override the css of App.vue in the following way but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<style scoped>
[data-vuetify] {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
[data-vuetify] .v-application--wrap {
  min-height: 0vh !important;
}
</style>
```

Here's how App.vue looks like:

```
<template>
  <div data-vuetify>
    <v-app id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
section {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
[data-vuetify] {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
[data-vuetify] .v-application--wrap {
  min-height: 0vh !important;
}
</style>
```

[image: Vuetify widget empty space in height]

Comment: Please improve your question by adding the relevant code to reproduce your issue (the template markup is missing)

Comment: @petey I have updated the question but the template is very short. I get this extra space even on a empty page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
 ::v-deep .v-application--wrap {
    min-height: fit-content;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and I have solved it as follows:

```
<style>
  .v-application--wrap {
    min-height: 0vh !important;
  }
</style>
```

In App.vue

Also, I have built it as a library using vue-cli

I'm new to Vue and Vuetify.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try unsetting it via CSS in your **App.vue** file:

```
<style>
.v-application--wrap {
  min-height: unset;
}
</style>
```

It should unset the default rule "*min-height: 100vh;*".

Answer (score 1):

For me, I removed `<v-app>` from the component and added it to the enclosing page (I'm using Nuxt) which removed the extra space from the component.

Answer (score 1):

**In Vue3 class name Changed**
old class name :**v-application--wrap**
new class name:**v-application__wrap**

```
<style>
.v-application__wrap {
  min-height: 0vh !important;
}
</style>
```

I hope this help you !