# Resizing <v-Main> to account for margins

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Using Vuetify I have a template structure like this:

```
<v-layout >
    <HeaderBar height="64"/> <!-- Loads a template with a <v-app-bar/>... -->
    <SideMenu height="100%"/> <!-- Loads a template with a <v-navigation-drawer/>... -->
    <v-app-bar height="48"/>
    <v-main >
        <router-view /> <!-- Loads a template with a <responsive><v-row><v-card>... -->
    </v-main>
    <FooterBar height="48"/> <!-- Loads a template with a <v-app-bar/>... -->
</v-layout>
```

What I've found is v-main height and y position do not account for the heights of the header and app-bar.  So I apply a margin to align it under the header and ap-bar.  This results in scrollbars, even when the v-main is empty.

Is there is a way to resize v-main to fit it's content to ensure scrollbars are only shown if the content is in fact taller than the space between app-bar and footer?

This same issue is described here:
[What with v-main can i delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584160/what-with-v-main-can-i-delete-it)

Tony19's proposed answer on that page includes a demo link that shows the scroll bars even though the content doesn't require scroll bars.  This is exactly what I want to avoid.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vuetify-v-app-example-uobps?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A44%2C16

Comment: In the sandbox, there is a CSS rule on `#app` (in App.vue), setting `margin-top: 60px`. If you remove that rule, the layout works as expected. The sandbox uses Vuetify 2 btw, if you use v3, the example might not work for you. In that case, consider creating a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/) for your example.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.
In the demo you provide, if I add an <app-bar> as a footer and header, the scrollbars appear.

Comment: I traced it back to adding the router-view.  I removed everything and added it back piece by piece.  I wasn't getting scrollbars until I add the router-view. 

The router-view can contain simply a template with just the line <p>Hello</p> and it appears to be the entire height of the window.  So is there perhaps a way to prevent that?  I don't think I have anything in my code that is setting the route-view to be 100% height.

Comment: I ended up resolving by adjusting the min-height of .v-application__wrap

I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039544/vuetify-changing-min-height-of-v-application-wrap

I just had to modify the class name as follows:
<style scoped lang="scss">
 ::v-deep .v-application__wrap {
    min-height: fit-content;
  }
</style>